# Why is servlet response not showing in my JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I am going through a book to learn ajax and I am stuck as my Servlet response (just text) is not showing up in my JavaScript in an alert.  When the button is clicked it calls a JavaScript function and then an http request get sent asynchronously.

I don't understand why the String is not showing in the response.  Thanks for any light anyone can shed on this.

EDIT: Also, I get a status code of 200 after sending the "get" request.  When I look at firebug under console I see the Get request with 200 status code.  There a 3 tabs - Params, Headers, and XML.  Under Params I see my dummy parameter that I send in the request.  Under Headers there are 2 nodes - 
Response Headers and Request Headers.  When I expand the Response Header node I see a thing called content-length with a 0 after it. Does that mean there is nothing in my response???

Here is my HTML

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Boards 'R' Us</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boards.css" media="screen" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="text-utils.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="boards.js"> </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1>Boards 'R' Us :: How Much Butt We're Kicking</h1>
  <div id="boards">
   <table>
    <tr><th>Snowboards Sold</th>
     <td><span id="boards-sold">1672</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th>What I Sell 'em For</th>
     <td>$<span id="boards-price">249.95</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th>What it Costs Me</th>
     <td>$<span id="boards-cost">84.22</span></td></tr>
   </table>
   <table>
    <tr><th>Boots Sold</th>
     <td><span id="boots-sold">312</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th>What I Sell 'em For</th>
     <td>$<span id="boots-price">175.47</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th>What it Costs Me</th>
     <td>$<span id="boots-cost">54.23</span></td></tr>
   </table>
   <table>
    <tr><th>Bindings Sold</th>
     <td><span id="bindings-sold">82</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th>What I Sell 'em For</th>
     <td>$<span id="bindings-price">146.92</span></td></tr>
    <tr><th>What it Costs Me</th>
     <td>$<span id="bindings-cost">98.03</span></td></tr>
   </table>
   <h2>Cash for the Slopes: 
    $<span id="cash">318936.42</span></h2>
   <form>
    <input value="Show Me the Money" type="button" 
           onClick="getNewTotals();" /> 
   </form>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and my JavaScript

```
function getNewTotals() {
    console.log("Getting new totals");
    var url = "boards.do";
    url = url + "?dummy=" + new Date().getTime();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
    request.send(null);
}

function updatePage() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            var reply = request.responseText;
            alert("returned: " + reply);
        } else {
            alert("Error! Request status = " + request.status);
        }
    }
}
```

and my Servlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.gmail.gmjord.controller.BoardSalesController;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class BoardSalesController
 */
//@WebServlet("/BoardSalesController")
public class BoardSalesController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BoardSalesController.class.getClass().getName());
    private static final Level INFO = Level.INFO;
    private static final Level[] LEVELS = {Level.SEVERE, Level.WARNING, Level.INFO, Level.CONFIG,
        Level.FINE, Level.FINER, Level.FINEST};

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public BoardSalesController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LOGGER.log(INFO, "in doGet()");
        String info = request.getParameter("dummy");
        LOGGER.log(INFO, "Request info: " + info);
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String reply = "Do you see this?";
        response.getWriter().write(reply);


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, what *is* happening?  Run it in a debugger and observe the network traffic.  Put a breakpoint in updatePage and see if it is called and how.

Comment: You could use Chrome or Firefox dev tools or even firebug to check XMLHttpRequest traffic and check what happens with it. You could also check other response statuses apart from 200 (Maybe a 404 or 500 error is being produced)

Comment: @Malvolio, thank you for reminding me that I can debug JavaScript - still new at this.  I debugged it in firebug and request.responseText is showing a value of "".  So I think somehow the Servlet is not sending the response properly.  Still investigating.

Comment: @mitchj -- what about the state and the status?  (My bet: status is 500.)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you're calling the `servlet` correctly and getting the response with an `http-header` status = 200, however you aren't receiving the string content, isn't it?

Then I think you have to call `flush()` on the writer to commit the response. If you check the `getWriter()` in `javax.servlet.ServletResponse` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter()) which is the interface of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` you can see this:

> Calling flush() on the PrintWriter commits the response.

However this is normally not necessary because `servlet container` do that for you, however in your case seems not so try with this code in the `doGet` method on your servlet:

```
String reply = "Do you see this?";
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write(reply);
writer.flush();
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I tried it this way and it didn't help.  I'm not sure what happened but after over several hours of trying to figure this out it mysteriously started working.

I have had other mysterious happenings with trying to run web apps that would sometimes not load all JavScripts, etc but then magically start doing it again.

I'm voting up for trying to help me!  Thank you!!  I wish I could vote all up.

Comment: Thanks to you `:)`. At first it sounds strange to me because normally servlet container do the `flush()`, however could be possible that something is happening behind the scene so I try with the answer. It's sad when strange things starts happen, maybe you can try with a fresh install of your web container `:)`.